# The lifetime of self parameter in Rust when using threads

Tags: rust

I'm in the process of learning Rust and I have this code:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread::spawn;

pub struct MyText {
    my_text: Mutex<Vec<String>>,
}

pub trait MyTextOptions {
    fn add(&self, t: String);
}

impl MyTextOptions for MyText {
    fn add(&self, text: String) {
        let int_text = Arc::new(self);
        let put_into_my_text = spawn(move || {
            let mut text_feed = int_text.my_text.lock().unwrap();
            text_feed.push(text)
        });
        put_into_my_text.join();
    }
}
```

When I try to run it I get:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src\buffer.rs:37:33
   |
37 |         let int_text = Arc::new(self);
   |                                 ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 36:5...
  --> src\buffer.rs:36:5
   |
36 | /     fn add(&self, text: String) {
37 | |         let int_text = Arc::new(self);
38 | |         let put_into_my_text = spawn(move || {
39 | |             let mut text_feed = int_text.my_text.lock().unwrap();
...  |
42 | |         put_into_my_text.join();
43 | |     }
   | |_____^
   = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
           expected &buffer::MyText
              found &buffer::MyText
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the type `[closure@src\buffer.rs:38:38: 41:10 int_text:std::sync::Arc<&buffer::MyText>, text:std::string::String]` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src\buffer.rs:38:32
   |
38 |         let put_into_my_text = spawn(move || {
   |
```

I seem to fail to understand the lifetime of variables in rust when using threads. No matter what I do with this function I'm still getting this type of error.

Comment: Basically, you're borrowing `self` for the duration of that function. The thread can outlive that function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A thread spawned via `thread::spawn` can in theory outlive its parent thread. If the child thread could reference data from the parent thread, these reference would dangle (be invalid) when the parent thread stops. This is expressed as a `'static` bound on the closure given to `thread::spawn`. The fact that you `join` the thread in the same function is not understood by the compiler, so the restriction still holds.

You already tried to use an `Arc` (presumably to get around this problem), but you are creating an `Arc` of `self` which is a reference already. So you are just putting a reference into an `Arc`. That value does not satisfy the `'static` bound, that's why you are getting an error.

There are multiple ways to solve this problem, many depend on the overall architecture of your project. One of the easiest ways is to use `scoped` from `crossbeam` (or specifically, `crossbeam_utils`):

```rust
use crossbeam_utils::thread;

impl MyTextOptions for MyText {
    fn add(&self, text: String) {
        thread::scope(|s| {
            s.spawn(|_| {
                let mut text_feed = self.my_text.lock().unwrap();
                text_feed.push(text)
            });
        }).unwrap();
    }
}
```

This is a fancy helper function that actually lets you borrow values from the parent scope by ensuring the child thread ends before the parent thread does.

Another solution would be to put the `MyText` value into an `Arc` (notably: by value, not by reference). Then you can clone this `Arc` a bunch of times and send it to a new thread. But this means you cannot use methods that take `&self` as receiver, but you have to solve it in another way.

Comment: Thanks, but when I implement it like this I get:
```30 | impl MyTextOptions for MyText {
   |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^- help: indicate the anonymous lifetime: `<'_>```. By the way I'm still using the ```        let int_text = Arc::new(self.clone());
```

Comment: I don't get the above error with this solution anymore.

Comment: `The fact that you join the thread in the same function is not understood by the compiler...` Why...?